# wordpress javascript echo Numeric

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jquery-ui

My script :

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableZtour = [<?php query_posts('category_name=ztour&showposts=5&orderby=date'); if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>"<?php the_title(); ?>",<?php }} wp_reset_query(); ?>];
$( "#ztour" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableZtour
});
```

If i'm add – weird hyphen => script echo – weird hyphen
but: i'm add `-` normal hyphen => script echo `&#8211;`

in post title i'm add: `This - is - post` in html source: `var availableZtour = ["This &#8211; is &#8211; post",]`

How? when i'm add `-` normal hyphen => script echo `-`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside WordPress, a couple functions are registered to handle the `the_title` hook automatically. One of them is [`wptexturize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize), which converts quotes to "smart quotes" and turns some special characters into their respective HTML entities.

You should be able to remove it with something like `remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' )` before your loop. Otherwise, you could access `$post->post_title` directly, but then you're responsible for sanitizing it yourself.